# Scaling Images of Different Sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

A follow up to a previous question. I have started building my webpage with scalable images, in full width it looks like this:

[image: Full width]

When scaled down it looks like this:

[image: Scaled down]

As you can see the two right hand images don't seem to scale in line with the main image. Can you see a way of achieving this so it scales nicely?

Code here:

```
body 
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4c4c4c;
}

img
{
    width: inherit;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#wrapper
{
    width: 710px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main-column-left
{
    max-width: 66%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    float: left;
}

#main-column-right
{
    max-width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

#news-feature
{
    width: 471px;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*max-height: 100%;*/
    /*height: 330px;*/
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

#news-item-four
{
    width: 231px;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*max-height: 100%;*/
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

#news-item-five
{
    width: 231px;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*max-height: 100%;*/
    float: left;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="main-column-left">
                <div id="news-feature">
                    <img src="Images/News01.jpg" height="470" width="330" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="main-column-right">
                <div id="news-item-four">
                    <img src="Images/News04.jpg" width="230" height="160" />
                </div>

                <div id="news-item-five">
                    <img src="Images/News05.jpg" width="230" height="160" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <br class="clear" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you not get them all to the size you would like and wrap a div around them then resize the wrapper?

Comment: Are you not maintaining aspect ratio, or is the problem with the padding not scaling with the images, causing the right hand sides of them to be pushed off the viewing area?

Comment: The grey borders around the images don't scale in the same way. You should check how the widths of those borders are calculated. For instance, did you know that margin-bottom in percentages is calculated based on the width of the container, not the height?

Comment: I've found the answer to this and it involved ensuring the percentages for the columns were calculated precisely to match 100% of the centre column floated div. I guess that's the answer...